# Comparing an integer variable with character

Tags: c

I tried to compare a integer variable with character variable but I wasn't satisfied with the output.

code 1:THIS AS SUPPOSED PRINTED 'YES'

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int m=1;
    char c='1';

    if(c=='1')
    printf("yes");

return 0;
}
```

code2:THIS DOESN'T PRINT 'YES'

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int m=1;
    char c='1';

    if(c=='m')
    printf("yes");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `char c='m';` in the second part? Or `if (c==m)`?

Comment: Note that `1` and `'1'` are different integer values.

Comment: 'm' corresponds to 109. Pls checkout the ASCII table

Comment: You have written `c=='m'`. This means you're asking if the character variable `c` contains the literal value `'m'`. `c` does not contain this value, so `"yes"` is not printed.

Comment: Do you know what this `'A'`, or this `'B'` or any letter between single quotes _actually_ means.

Comment: Explain us why you think that code2 is supposed to print "YES". And also: do you think there is a relationship between the name of the variable `m` and the value `'m'`?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

`int m=1;` defines `m` to be an `int` object that is initially set to 1.

`char c='1';` defines `c` to be a `char` object that is initially set to the code number for the character “1”.

`c == '1'` compares the value of `c` to the code number for the character “1”. Since `c` contains the code value for the character “1”, it evaluates to true (represented as 1 in C).

`c == 'm'` compares the value of `c` to the code number for the character “m”. Since `c` contains the code value for the character “1“, not “m”, it evaluates to false (represented as 0 in C).

If you had written `c == m`, it would compare the value of `c` to the value of `m`. Since `c` contains the code value for the character “1” but `m` contains the value 1, it would evaluate to false in most C implementations. (Because most C implementations use some character encoding in which the code for “1” is some number other than 1. The character encoding is not completely specified by the C standard.)

Comment: brother can you please explain why this thing works:#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

 int m=1;
 char c=1;
 if(c==m)
 printf("yes");

return 0;
}

Comment: @AbhishekGuru: In that `m` has value 1, and `c` has value 1, so they are equal.

Comment: @AbhishekGuru: Something you might not be understanding is that `1` and `m` in C expressions are the values for the number 1 or the object named `m`, whereas `'1'` and `'m'` are the values for the codes for the characters “1” and “m”. Enclosing a character in apostrophes says to use the code for that character.

Answer (score 0):

`if(c=='m')` part is the problem here.

There is distinction between variable **m** and  *(char)* **'m'**:

If you want to use **m** as a variable name which holds a data. Just place it in an appropriate position in your code as **m** not '**m**'.

If you want to use 'm' value which is a character. Place it as **'m'** not **m**.

In your example you should change `if(c=='m')` to `if(c==m)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char c = '1';
```

Here, the char variable c is set to the character '1', which is integer value of 49 (Assuming ASCII encoding).

```
char c = 1;
```

here, the char variable c is set to the integer value 1.